# How to divide column in dataframe by values in a dict according to some key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with the columns `delta` and `integer_id`. I have a dict `d` that maps `integer_id` to some floating point value. I want to divide each row's `delta` in `df` by the corresponding value from `d` for the `integer_id`, and if the row's `integer_id` doesn't exist in the dict, leave `delta` unchanged.

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "integer_id": [1, 2, 3],
  "delta": [10, 20, 30]
})
d = {1: 0.5, 3: 0.25}
```

The result should be

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "integer_id": [1, 2, 3],
  "delta": [20, 20, 120] # note the middle element is unchanged
})
```

I tried `df["delta"] /= df.integer_id.map(d)`, but this will return `NaN` for the second row because `d` doesn't have the corresponding key. But something like

```
df["delta"] /= df.integer_id.map(lambda x: d.get(x, 1))
```

will get what I need, but I'm wondering what other approaches there are for this case?

Comment: Your `map` approach is ideal. You could also have used `df['integer_id'].map(d).fillna(1)`. In any case, don't use `apply`.

Comment: @mozway Is it because `apply` isn't as performant?

Comment: Yes, especially on `axis=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
  "integer_id": [1, 2, 3],
  "delta": [10, 20, 30]
})

d = {1: 0.5, 3: 0.25}

df['delta'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['delta']/d.get(r['integer_id'], 1), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply function and check if `integer_id in d`

```
df["delta"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["delta"] / d[row["integer_id"]] if row["integer_id"] in d else row["delta"], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["delta"] = df["delta"] / df["integer_id"].map(d).fillna(1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   integer_id  delta
0           1   20.0
1           2   20.0
2           3  120.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which converts the dictionary to a dataframe and then uses `merge`:

```
aux = df.merge(
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['Col'])
    .reset_index(names="integer_id"), how='left').fillna(1)
df.assign(res = aux['delta'].div(aux['Col']))
```

Output:

```
   integer_id  delta    res
0           1     10   20.0
1           2     20   20.0
2           3     30  120.0
```